# Parsing XML to CSV using xq and jq

Tags: xml, yq, xq

There is some terminal command for parsing xml to csv in python xq syntax (also python-yq installed required):

```
xq -r '[.yml_catalog.shop.offers.offer[] | [."@id", ."@available", .price, .name, .description]] | . |= [["id", "available", "price", "name", "description"]] + . | .[] | @csv' source.yml > result.csv
```

Here is xml file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <yml_catalog date="2020-07-29 09:39">
    <shop>
      <offers>
        <offer id="17489" available="true">
          <price>1500</price>
          <name>Item 1</name>
          <description>Item 1 description</description>
          <param name="category type">sale</param>
          <param name="size">big</param>
        </offer>
        <offer id="17490" available="false">
          <price>1100</price>
          <name>Item 2</name>
          <description>Item 2 description</description>
          <param name="category type">main</param>
          <param name="size">small</param>
        </offer>
        ...
      </offers>
    </shop>
  </yml_catalog>
```

I need to add param tags for parsing. I've tried to handle its by *."param[@name="category type"]"*, *."param[@name=category type]* (the same for the param tag with size attribute), but it doesn't work.

Necessary output csv:

```
"id","available","price","name","description","category","size"
"17489","true","1500","Item 1","Item 1 description","sale","big"
"17490","false","1100","Item 2","Item 2 description","main","small"
```

Please give me advice how to handle tags with exact properties with values and get its text text contents?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to convert the XML output to CSV, since [`xq` also uses `jq` syntax](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#xml-support) underneath, you can use the following

```
xq -r '["id","available","price","name","description","category","size"], 
       (.yml_catalog.shop.offers.offer[] | 
       [."@id", ."@available", .price, .name, .description, .param[]."#text"]) | 
       @csv' xml
```

Comment: Added necessary info to main question

Comment: @Aleksey: Could you  accept/upvote the answer if it solved your problem? See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)